# $(this) equivalent in CsQuery

Tags: jquery, html, csquery

is there equivalent for $(this) in csquery..
in below example letterbody string has html content. i want to prepand text before each tag.

```
 var dom = CQ.Create(letterBody);
            CQ divs = dom.Select("p");


  divs.Each(
                (index, domCQ) =>
                {
                    index = index + 1;
                    divs.Prepend("<span>" + index++ + "</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>");//how to access and prepand //to each selected divs..
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same as `.Cq()` in newer versions of CsQuery. `IDOMElement`s have a `.Cq()` extension method that does it.

```
 domEl.Cq().Text(); // for example
```